# Changing input_shape when copying Keras layers from one model to another

Tags: keras

I have a simple single-layer CNN network that I have trained.  I would now like to use this model without the top in order to visualize the CNN filters, as illustrated in the Keras.io blog post [here](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html).

This is my simple model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(24, (5, 5), padding='valid',input_shape=(1, 17,17), activation='relu',name='conv2d_1'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu',name='dens_1'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax',name='dens_2'))
```

I would like to load the model using `load_model`, and then create a topless model with a generic input size `(1, None,None)`, such as the model illustrated below.  Is this possible?  I prefer to not have to explicitly re-define all layers in the model.

```
model_no_top = Sequential()
model_no_top.add(Conv2D(24, (5, 5), padding='valid',input_shape=(1, None, None), activation='relu',name='conv2d_1'))
model_no_top.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model_no_top.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

I've loaded the model and grabbed the layers that I want, but the `input_shape` is the same as the original model.

```
model = load_model(model_path)
model_no_top = Sequential()
for layer in model.layers:
    if 'flatten' not in layer.name and 'dens' not in layer.name:
        model_no_top.add(layer)
```